# using C++ code in XCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I tried to import a C++ library into XCode, I renamed the .cpp to .mm but when I try to compile it shows me errors like this:

**DateOps.h:23: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_*attribute*_' before 'DateOps'**

start of DateOps.h file

```
#if !defined( DATE_OPS__H )
#define DATE_OPS__H

typedef int MonthDays[13];

typedef long YearEndDays[2];

class DateOps {
public:
  enum CalendarType {
    T_GREGORIAN = 0,
    T_JULIAN = 1,
  };
```

...

Comment: Show us the start of `DateOps.h` and also how you are including it.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have to compile a couple files as Objective-C++, then [the answer that WrightsCS gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10603441/1304626) will work fine. However, if you have lots of files to compile this way, or think your project will get bigger in the future, you can change the compilation language for all files:

Go to the **Build Settings** for your target, look under the **Language** section for a setting called **Compile Sources As**. Usually it is set to "According to File Type" (which should work with the .mm extension, but I've seen bugs where it still compiles as Objective-C before). You can force it to "Objective-C++" by changing this setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `-x objective-c++` as a **Compiler Flag** on the .mm file you are referring to.

[image]

Comment: I didn't have to do that and all my source files are Objective-C++.